# phantomJS - send page from client side to a server where listens phantomJS

Tags: select, phantomjs

I have a form where after submit client get resulting page which contains what client have chosen and also are displayed pictures for every items. This page I want to export to PDF. On my server run phantomJs and my idea is modify the resulting page to be possible sent that on the server where listens phantomjs.

the code which I have included into page which is rendered on client side:

```
<input type="submit" id="export-pdf" value="send" name="submit">

<script>
$('input#export-pdf').click(function(){

    var html = $("body").html();
    var data = { html: html };
    $.post("http://server_IP/create-pdf.php", data);
});                             
</script>
```

create-pdf.php (on server):

```
<?php
$html = $_POST['html'];
file_put_contents("tmp.html", $html);
exec("phantomjs tmp.html tmp.pdf");
$pdf = file_get_contents("tmp.pdf");
header("content-type: application/pdf");
echo $pdf;
exit;
?>
```

so far I did not get any pdf...what I am doing wrongly?....
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about this, but u could try with the js api with the call.
exec("phantomjs rasterize.js tmp.html tmp.pdf")

Answer (score 0):

I stop the rendering with Phantom Js and now I do it via mPDF php library